# GWT extract all value from a row in a flextable

Tags: java, gwt, flextable

i have a flextable with many row and 5 colums, i need to extract all value from a specific row when i select one. The value must appears on a window. How can i do?

Comment: you need to extract html contents of all the cells in a row?

Comment: yes i need to click on a row and show a window on screen which contains all value of the row clicked

Answer (score 2):

You can get access to contents of any table td element using the code below:

```
flexTable.getFlexCellFormatter().getElement(row, column).getInnerHTML()
```

Comment: thx but i receive all html value with div <div class="gwt-Label">1</div>  is possible obtain only the value?

Comment: in this case you better use ((Label)flexTable.getWidget(row, column)).getValue()

Comment: Yes .That's better approach .

Answer (score 2):

If you know the row number ,you can get each element  by using

```
flexTable.getWidget(rowNum,colNum ).getelement().getInnerHtml();//will give with html tags
```

You can iterate throughout the flex table also like below .

```
   Iterator<Widget> widgetiterator = flexTable.iterator();
              while (widgetiterator.hasNext()){
                Widget childWidget = widgetiterator.next();
                if (childWidget instanceof RadioButton) { //Example
                ((RadioButton) childWidget).getValue(); 

                }
              }
```

And

```
Widget w flexTable.getWidget(rowNum,colNum );
 if (w instanceof TextBox) {
//TO Do get value
```